# subtract two times in php and laravel 24H

Tags: php, string, time, dateinterval

This seems like a fairly simple question, but I'm having trouble with it!
In my request, I have two fields

```
$takeOffTime = '23:00';
$landingTime = '01:05';
```

I want to subtract breakout from break in to get the difference, and then take that number and subtract it from the difference between takeOffTime and landingTime.

How can I do this **in 24H formt 'h:i**'?

```
$takeOff = '23:00';
$landing = '01:10';

$t1 = strtotime($takeOff);
$t2 = strtotime($landing);
```

Comment: I don't know if this is something in production but you should take care of timezones in this context and not work with plain hour and minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subtract two times to `H:i`  format like this.

```php
$takeOff = '23:00';
$landing = '01:10';

$t1 = strtotime($takeOff);
$t2 = strtotime($landing);

$diff = gmdate('H:i', $t2 - $t1);

dd($diff); // "02:10"
```

Answer (score 2):

With DateTime diff you can calculate the DateInterval, then format the DateInterval with format,

```
$takeOff = '23:00';
$landing = '01:05';
$take_off_date = new DateTime('23:00');
$landing_date = new DateTime('01:05');
if($landing <= $takeOff){
    $landing_date->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
}
echo ($landing_date->diff($take_off_date))->format("%H:%I");
```

output `02:05`

Comment: thanks. but I want to give me a diff  from 23:00 pm to 01:00 am .output is ```02:05```.try my code please.